# ng-table is not working properly when using json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using a json file to render information in to my Angular ng-table. It's listing all the information from json as a normal table but ng-table functions such as pagination, view limit are not working.

I'm getting following error in console.

***TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined***

My codes,

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngTable']);

    app.service('tableService', ['$resource', function($resource){
            this.getTableData = function(id, email, date) {
                var tableDataList = $resource("table.json");

                return tableDataList.get ({
                    id: id,
                    email: email,
                    date: date
                })
            }
    }])

    app.controller('tableCtrl', function($scope, tableService, ngTableParams) {

                //Data
                $scope.id = tableService.id;
                $scope.email = tableService.email;
                $scope.date = tableService.date;

                $scope.dtResult = tableService.getTableData(this.id, this.email, this.date);


                $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1,            // show first page
                    count: 10           // count per page
                }, {
                    total: $scope.dtResult.length, // length of data
                    getData: function ($defer, params) {
                       $defer.resolve($scope.dtResult.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    }
                })

    });
```

HTML

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
              <tr ng-repeat="w in dtResult.list">
                  <td data-title="'ID'">
                      {{ w.id }}
                  </td>
                  <td data-title="'Email Address'">
                      {{ w.email }}
                  </td>
                  <td data-title="'Date'">
                      {{ w.date }}
                  </td>
              </tr>
</table>
```

Plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/bdWB98cAyhWTbXg8KgGx?p=preview

Please help me.

Comment: Put a square bracket around your data and make it an ARRAY. `[$scope.dtResult = tableService.getTableData(this.id, this.email, this.date);]`

Answer (score 0):

Change this in `tableService`

```
 var tableDataList = $resource('table.json',{ }, {
        getData: {method:'GET', isArray: false}
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Even after your code, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.dtResult` is first set to the result of a `get` from a `$resource`:

```
$scope.dtResult = tableService.getTableData(...)
```

Then later:

```
$scope.dtResult.slice(...)
```

The error probably comes from the above line.

According to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource): "It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray)." -- So it looks like that `$scope.dtResult` will initially be an empty object here (eventually, once the `get` returns some results, it will be filled in). Maybe all you need is to use `query` instead of `get` so that the result will be an array?

**EDIT:**

Looking at the latest plunkr in the comments, the actual error is `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. This is different from the original one in the question. `dtResult` is there, but it has no `slice` function. Which is not surprising, as the data (again, from the plunkr) is like this:

```
{
  list: [
    {...},
    ...
  ]
}
```

So you have an object with a list in it, and it is this list you want to show in the table.

I think in this case you can't really use the trick offered by $resource to avoid using a callback (where it first returns an empty object/array, then it populates the details later, updating the bound view automatically). You need to use the `$promise` directly, as suggested by @Akshay Dhankhar in the other answer. The "official" [server-side list example](http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/VLqqjP?editors=101) for [ng-table](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) is also very similar to this.

So: instead of calling `tableService.getTableData` first, do it inside your `getData` function and resolve the deferred object for the table when the result actually comes back:

```
// no need for this: $scope.dtResult = tableService.getTableData(this.id, this.email, this.date);

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}, {
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
      tableService.getTableData($scope.id, $scope.email, $scope.date).$promise.then(function(data) {
         params.total(data.list.length);
         $defer.resolve(data.list.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
      });
    }
})
```

In the HTML, use `$data` as your list:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="w in $data">
        <td data-title="'ID'">
        ...
```

Comment: I've printed dtResult and it has values. It's not empty. Even I tried changing get to query but no luck. Could you please help me in anyway?

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace for the error? Is it really coming from that line with `slice` in `getData` -- or from somewhere else? Where are you printing `dtResult`? Try setting a breakpoint or print it from multiple places to get an idea about where it's changed...

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in return from service you are getting the $promise and $promise should take time in guarantee you the data.

Look at the code i did some changes and then proceed with your other stuff.

[Link to plunkar](http://plnkr.co/Z4e7l6T619Rrg4Qw2IJz?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngTable']);

app.service('tableService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    this.getTableData = function(id, email, date) {
        var tableDataList = $resource("table.json");

        return tableDataList.get ({
            id: id,
            email: email,
            date: date
        }).$promise;
    }
}])

app.controller('tableCtrl', function($scope, tableService, ngTableParams) {

    //Data
    $scope.id = tableService.id;
    $scope.email = tableService.email;
    $scope.date = tableService.date;

    tableService.getTableData(this.id, this.email, this.date).then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $scope.dtResult = data.list;
      $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
    }, {
        total: $scope.dtResult.length, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {

          $defer.resolve($scope.dtResult.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });

    });



});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Any idea why pagination and view limit is not working?

Comment: I've posted my plunkr above. in your plunkr demo, pagination is listed but not working, all the rows are rendered already and when clicking the pagin, nothing happens. I just need a fix for that. Thank you.